# Вопросы в работе Java с интерфейсом Windows

Tags: java

Добрый день! 
Суть проблемы **заключается скорее в незнании терминологии**, в следствии чего возникает проблема с **поиском необходимой документации**. Итак.

Существует некая выполняющаяся в фоне программа, производящие некоторую работу с сервером. Проблему же вызывают два момента реализации:

- При нажатии определённой комбинации клавиш программа должна вставлять
  информацию (текст) в текстовое поле, на которое в данный момент
  фокусируется интерфейс Windows (опять же, если я правильно использую
  терминологию).
- При нажатии другой комбинации клавиш программа должна наоборот,
  копировать выделенный текст в свой буфер.

То есть программа должна иметь свой собственный, выделенный под мои нужды дополнительный буфер обмена. Вариант с автоматическим копированием из буфера или вставкой информации при получении не является подходящим мне.

Возможно кто-нибудь знает, как подобные вещи называются, и где мне искать документацию на этот счёт или решения. Если же кто-то сразу готов дать решение этих моментов реализации, я буду очень благодарен.

P.S. Так же, в будущем программа подразумевает подобную работу с файлами (загружая их на сервер или с сервера в фокусируемую область explorer-а), поэтому, если кто-то подскажет как мне реализовать это для интерфейса explorer-а, опять же буду благодарен.

UPD 1.
Нашёл библиотеку JNA, попробую разобраться с ней, хотя не уверен, что там есть необходимые мне мосты. И даже, если и есть, то вопрос всё равно остаётся открытым.

Answer (score 1):

То что вам нужно это "глобальный перехват подставить_нужное", а именно перехват клавы(глобальный потому что обрабатывается до текущего активного приложения). Так же вам понадобится перехват "каретки"(это мигающая полоска при вводе текста). Сразу предупреждаю, что это делается на С\С++ через winAPI и наврятли для этого будет Java-обёртка(но возможно и найдётся библиотека\код на гитхабе или в гугле).

Comment: Каретка! Вот этот термин, огромное спасибо (да, весь всё просто, хех)! Уже нашёл  обёртку для обработки клавиш, для каретки же, я думаю, найти не составит труда. Тогда может подскажете, как по-умному называется выделяемый текст?

Comment: @Янислав в русском как "выделенный текст" в английском "selected text" а функции что то вроде GetSelText().
Вам в первую очередь надо порыться в winAPI, дабы узнать как 

1) как узнать о создании каретки 
2) как получить ID окна 
3) как послать в окно сообщение 
4) как работать с буфером обмена

А уже после этого искать обёртки на Java

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам надо считывать данные в переменную, а после по назначенным клавишам заносить туда данные или наоборот копировать

Comment: Эм, мне кажется, что это весьма очевидный факт. И  никак не помогает решению проблемы. Мне как раз и нужна помощь в том, как считывать эти данные с помощью интерфейса Windows.